# Selenium + Python erro ao usar time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Estou automatizando uma tarefa em um website usando python + selenium.
Toda vez que uso o `time.sleep()` vai executar o tempo de sleep retorna esse erro.

> ```
> ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] Uma conexão estabelecida foi anulada pelo software no computador host
> ```

Alguem sabe a causa e como eu poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Não colocamos "resolvido" no título. Apenas marcamos a resposta adequada como aceita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso parece ser um problema do `geckodriver` 0.21.0, se estiver usando essa versão.

Tente usar a [0.20.1](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.20.1) por enquanto.

Comment: Opa, voltei uma versao anterior e agora esta indo. Valeu!!

Comment: @JarleiSassi de nada! Se resolveu a pergunta, não esqueça de aceitar a resposta clicando no "V" verde pra marcá-la como resolvida.